# Emphasizing the subject with an article

Tags: sentence-choice, subjects

What is the difference from including the article in the emphasis (which is not for intonation but for formatting)?

> He is [a journalist](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/317864/emphasizing-the-subject-with-an-article) based in LA.

> He is a [journalist](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/317864/emphasizing-the-subject-with-an-article) based in LA.

P.s. I edited the question because I was not clear.

Comment: Can you provide examples of real sentences where you have actually heard **the** emphasised? I don't think it really works in either of the examples that you have quoted.

Comment: In Britain we can say 'the' as 'thee' (like before a vowel) with emphasis, if we are talking about something uniquely special, or supposed to  be so _The Ford Cortina is **the** car for family men in 1962_ or to clarify if someone famous is being discussed, or just someone with the same name _In 1995 my sister was dating Michael Jackson. What, **the** Michael Jackson? The singer? No, Michael Jackson a bank clerk from Doncaster._

Comment: Whenever there is an implied comparison, emphatic _the_ serves as a superlative marker: _He's **the** man to see about that. "The Skylight" is **the** hot Broadway ticket_. But it doesn't occur with [generic noun phrases like _the tiger_](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html).

Comment: If we emphasize the **a** - he is **a** journalist based in L.A. - we are saying he's not the only one. If someone mentions a singer, saying, "He's the Welsh singer", we might say, "He's **a** Welsh singer: he's not the _only_ one."